# Create rails locale yaml file automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, mongodb, mongomapper

is it possible to create / update a locale language yaml file from with a rails application ?

If so is would it be automatically pulled into the load path somehow as i dont want to have to restart to pull in the new changes ?

Is this possble and if so how ??   or is there a better way ?

I am using mongodb as a db.

thanks
rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is awesome:

https://www.github.com/mynewsdesk/translate

:)